# expected Declaration (Won't Compile)

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently working on a project and this won't compile.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        self.contacts.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }

}
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.

return true
```

Comment: How can the code crash? It won't even compile.

Comment: You have a `return true` just sitting there outside any function; remove it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I'm assuming the `return true` does not belong there. You can't return a value outside of a method.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        self.contacts.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
}
```